# Listings: increase internal margin between caption (top) and listing?

Tags: listings

With the MWE below (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741985/latex-source-code-listing-like-in-professional-books)), how do I increase the internal margin in the listing so that instead of looking like this:

[image]

It looks like this (note the gray background has been "stretched" a bit):

[image]

I have tried fiddling with `framextopmargin`, `belowcaptionskip` etc but it doesn't seem to work with the *internal* margin.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{calc} 
\lstdefinestyle{outline}{
         basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
         numberstyle=\tiny,
         numbersep=5pt,
         tabsize=2,
         extendedchars=true,
         breaklines=true,
         keywordstyle=\color{blue},
         frame=b,
         stringstyle=\color{green!40!black}\ttfamily,
         showspaces=false,
         showtabs=false,
         numbers=left,
         xleftmargin=17pt,
         framexleftmargin=17pt,
         showstringspaces=false,
         backgroundcolor=\color[RGB]{200,200,200},
         belowcaptionskip=-1pt
}

\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox[RGB]{60,100,180}{\parbox{\textwidth - 2 \fboxsep}{\hspace{14pt}#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white, singlelinecheck=false, margin=0pt, font={bf,footnotesize}}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=outline,caption=Test]
First line.
Second line.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there needs to be a frame line on the top in order for `framextopmargin` to have any impact.  With the exception of a thin black line between the caption and frame itself, this is exactly what you asked for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{calc} 
\lstdefinestyle{outline}{
         basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
         numberstyle=\tiny,
         numbersep=5pt,
         tabsize=2,
         extendedchars=true,
         breaklines=true,
         keywordstyle=\color{blue},
         frame=bt,  % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
         stringstyle=\color{green!40!black}\ttfamily,
         showspaces=false,
         showtabs=false,
         numbers=left,
         xleftmargin=17pt,
         framexleftmargin=17pt,
         framextopmargin=1pt, % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
         showstringspaces=false,
         backgroundcolor=\color[RGB]{200,200,200},
         belowcaptionskip=0pt
}

\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox[RGB]{60,100,180}{\parbox{\textwidth - 2 \fboxsep}{\hspace{14pt}#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white, singlelinecheck=false, margin=0pt, font={bf,footnotesize}}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=outline,caption=Test]
First line.
Second line.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: frame]

#### Edit:

Possible solutions to the "black line" problem:

1. To remove both black lines so that they are "invisible", you can just add a `rulecolor` keyword to the listing style setup:

   ```
   rulecolor=\color[RGB]{200,200,200},
   ```
2. To actually remove the top line so that it doesn't print, but keep the bottom line, you want to keep `frame=bt` (since this is needed for the spacing), but add the following to the preamble after the style settings to set the rulewidth to 0 for just "Top" frames:

   ```
   \usepackage{etoolbox}
   \makeatletter
   \patchcmd{\lst@frameh}{\color@begingroup}{\color@begingroup\if#2T\let\lst@framerulewidth\z@ \fi}{}{}
   \makeatother
   ```

Of these two solutions, I would personally prefer the first, as I don't think the single black line on the bottom is that appealing visually.

Comment: Yes, that seems so. Except from the black line between the caption and frame. Is there any way to remove it?

Comment: @johnrl, see edited answer.  The second solution takes care of the single line through a patch to the internal command that draws the frame borders.